# How to move a chart (Highcharts) using the arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How do I move a chart using HighCharts instead of moving with the mouse to the right and left, I would like to use the directional keys (right key, left key, key up, key down)

http://goo.gl/oJ71Dx

This example uses the mouse to move, i need to do with the keys, could anyone help me?

Comment: Look at [API][1], it can help you


  [1]: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock

Answer (score 0):

You can handle arrow event and set needded dates in from and to inputs

```
$(".highcharts-range-selector[name='min']").val("some date")
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
But i could not use it because there may be several repeated dates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch key press event (by i.e jquery) and call [setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes), defaulty it is not supported.